# How to "split up" or optimize a Linq to Sql query.

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

### Background

We have a `AdvancedSearchModel` which is just a struct with several strings. `SerialNumbers` is a string of serial numbers (10 characters in length) separated by commas. This is split into an array of strings. We are searching over a table `Devices` which has a column, `SerialNumber`. We need to partial match these search phrases as well, which explains the `Any` and `Contains` usage. There are about 10 strings in the `AdvancedSearchModel` and we are able to apply each to the query without issue.

```
public static IQueryable<Device> ApplySearchQuery(IQueryable<Device> query, AdvancedSearchModel searchModel)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchModel.SerialNumbers))
    {
        string[] serialNumbers = searchModel.SerialNumbers.Split(',');
        query = query.Where(d => serialNumbers.Any(s => d.SerialNumber.Contains(s))); 

     }
     // ... more queries added that are part of the search model
}
```

### The Issue

Let me preface this with when this was implemented, we expected about 10 serial numbers to be search at once max. *However*, We've found users putting up to 100 Serial numbers. We get an error that the query is too deeply nested from this. So even if we only search by SerialNumbers, it will throw an exception when `serialNumbers` grows above 43 elements.

I'm not really sure how to split up this query, as individually they are simple (albeit we expect the result to be slow).

Perhaps we could have an `ArrayList` of `string[]` of size ~25, and grow this array list, ie if a user searches for 100 serial numbers, then the `ArrayList` would have 4 string arrays, but I'm not sure that really helps...

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you just split the serial numbers into batches of 25 serial numbers and make multiple searches?

Comment: I'm currently trying this ^, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: What exception are you getting when the array grows beyond 43 serials?

Comment: System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException - Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Batching seems to be working, I'll add it as an answer I guess.

Comment: Nevermind, I wasn't batching it correctly. I'm not sure how to union together the multiple where clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you can get EF to generate a flat OR statement instead of a nested subquery if you generate the OR expression manually:

```
string[] serialNumbers = searchModel.SerialNumbers.Split(',');
// GetMethod defined at http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-two/
var stringContainsMethod = Helpers.GetMethod((string s) => s.Contains(default(string)));
var serialNumberProperty = Helpers.GetProperty((Device d) => d.SerialNumber);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Device));

// generate a condition d.SerialNumber.Contains(sn) for each sn
var conditions = serialNumbers.Select(sn => Expression.Call(  
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, serialNumberProperty), // d.SerialNumber
    stringContainsMethod, // the method to invoke
    Expression.Constant(sn) // equivalent of a string literal for the serial number
));

// generate a lambda we can pass to Where: 
// d => d.SerialNumber.Contains(sn1) || d.SerialNumber.Contains(sn1) || ..
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Device, bool>>(
    // merge each condition with ORs
    conditions.Aggregate<Expression>((c1, c2) => Expression.OrElse(c1, c2)),
    parameter
);

// apply the predicate
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Batching will also, work of course. However, it shouldn't be necessary for so small an argument set.

Comment: What class is GetProperty a function of? I don't see it in the code ducky namespaces.

Comment: I got this working, I implemented the GetProperty function... Although I'd like to understand how it all works a little more!

Comment: @Dave: as it sounds like you surmised, GetProperty is just another variant of GetMethod() and has a very similar implementation. As far as understanding things better, which part do you have questions about?

Comment: Creating the condition is a little confusing. What is Expression.Constant(sn) do?

Comment: @Dave: it's passing the given serial number as a constant. This is what you'd get if you created an expression that searched for a string literal.